# What are the Win Conditions?

Tags: hero-academy

In Hero Academy, do I just need to knock out and then stomp all opponents currently in play to win?  Or do I need to do that for *all* opponents they have in their deck/stack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can win a Hero Academy match in two different ways, actually.

1. Destroy the enemy's crystals.  In each map the enemy will have at least one, but maybe more crystals that they are tasked with defending.  If you destroy all of the enemy's crystals, then you will be declared the victor.
2. Destroy all of your opponents units.  This includes any units that are in their deck/stack that they have yet to deploy.  If only the current units in play are destroyed, the enemy will still be allowed to spawn new units from their stack at the start of their next turn.

Comment: So, assuming I manage to destroy all units in play I have free reign until they are able to deploy another unit (admittedly that will probably be on the next turn anyway...)

Comment: @Rob That is correct.  If you, say, destroy all enemy units on your second action point, you then still have three more action points to do whatever you want, be it moving your own units or attacking their crystals.